# azure function: set blob filename from http request

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I am trying to set an azure function to upload a blob from an HTTP request to a blob.

I was able to use the following for uploading a file with a static filename:

```
public static class Uploader
{
    [FunctionName("Uploader")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req,
    [Blob("hello/uploaded.jpg", FileAccess.Write)]Stream writer,
    TraceWriter log
    )
        {
            log.Info("trigger for image upload started...");
            if (!req.ContentType.Contains("multipart/form-data") || (req.Form.Files?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
            {
                log.Warning("no images found on upload attempt");
                return new BadRequestResult();
            }
            foreach (var file in req.Form.Files)
                file.CopyTo(writer.);

            return new OkObjectResult("Done!");
        }
}
```

Is there any way I could alter `Blob("hello/uploaded.jpg")` into something like `Blob("hello/{fileName}"` to get the name dynamically the HTTP request. I don't mind if it's anywhere from the head or body. I am trying to not use the whole `GetBlockBlobReference` process just for the dynamic file name alone.

**Update**
I am not sure if I am missing something or looking at this problem the wrong way. For a serverless set up with a blob storage isn't an HTTP upload supposed to be an obvious and common scenario? How come there aren't any examples for this?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/401

Answer (score 4):

The option suggested by @RomanKiss should work. Alternatively, if you want you can put filename into the function URL template:

```cs
[FunctionName("Uploader")]
public static IActionResult Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "uploader/{filename}")] 
  HttpRequest req,
  string filename,
  [Blob("hello/{filename}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream writer,
  TraceWriter log)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the following is an example with both an HttpRequestMessage and a POCO binding:

```
[FunctionName("Uploader")]
public static IActionResult Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] Info input, HttpRequest req,
[Blob("hello/{FileName}", FileAccess.Write)]Stream writer,
TraceWriter log
)
{
   //...
}

public class Info
{
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   //...
}
```

Update:

The following snippet shows an example for using an expanding HttpTrigger binding data support with a well-known properties such as *headers* and *query*, more details [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/pull/225):

```
[FunctionName("Uploader")]
public static IActionResult Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)HtpRequest req,
  [Blob("hello/{query.filename}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream writer,
  // [Blob("hello/{headers.filename}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream writer,
  TraceWriter log)
{
   //...
}
```

sample of url:
http://localhost:7071/api/Uploader?filename=uploaded.jpg

Comment: This doesn't work with `HttpRequest req`. `req` needs the HTTP trigger too

Comment: i also just noticed that file name needs to be a get param

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, I've just tried and it is working fine for me. which version of the function sdk are you using ?

Comment: SDK is 1.0.6. I am trying 1.0.10 now

Comment: @Thomas tried 10 as well, the same issue. What exactly worked for you?

Comment: The binding. My function is reached and I am able to write the file

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your solution

Comment: tried a couple of times with clean. it shows `Cannot bind parameter 'req' to type HttpRequest. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions`
not sure if i need some set up for this

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Try the HttpRequestMessage type.

Comment: nop... i am still getting  `Cannot bind parameter 'req' to type HttpRequestMessage. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding`